# A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I try adding list item using REST in SharePoint 2013.  when code is try add new item in list , getting error :

```
"{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
  "message":
     {"lang":"en-US","value":"A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected."}}}"
```

**My code**

var addNewTask = function() {

```
    var data = {
        __metadata: {
            'type': 'SP.Data.Asana2ListItem'
        },
        Title: "dd",
        PriorityCod: "1",
        Category: "1",
        Desc2: "dd",
        AssignedTo: "Lynda",
        CONTRACT_HDR_ID: "1"
    };

    //console.log(tsk.AssignedUserId);
    //kkk
    var hostweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
        );
    var appweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
        );
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);

    function execCrossDomainRequest() {
        // executor: The RequestExecutor object
        // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the add-in web URL.
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl +
                "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/GetByTitle('Asana2')/items/?@target='" +
                hostweburl + "'",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            "X-HTTP-Method": "POST",
            "content-length": 50,
            "If-Match": "*",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: successHandler1,
            error: errorHandler1
        });
    }

    function successHandler1(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    function errorHandler1(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Need help. I am new to sharepoint

Comment: Check my solution

Comment: Can you give me a link to your solution

Comment: Why do u need that? posted my solution again. See now

Comment: Hey, check it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `RequestExecutor`, I think you are looking for body instead of data. Try replacing `data: JSON.stringify(data)` with `body:JSON.stringify(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `data: JSON.stringify(data)` with `body:JSON.stringify(data)`.

This worked for me.

thank you.