# SharePoint POST REST API returning error code 400

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, http-400-bad-request, java

I'm attempting to create an item in SharePoint on premise 2016 list using Java and SharePoint API. Forgive me if I missed it - I see a few related questions but they do not seem to really answer my question.

I'm able to do GET and fetch digest value. I am getting error code 400 when attempting to create a list item.

Questions:

1. Do I still need to worry about authentication? As added complication, I'm attempting to do this using a chatbot attached to internal company messaging system. The sharepoint list is also internal and I never really had to worry about authentication when doing GET or fetching digest value. I'm hoping not because the code is 400, as opposed to 401 or 403
2. If I do not - from what I've read error 400 could be caused because of incorrect data format to be written into the list or some Java peculiarities with respect to setting Content-Length for output stream. Hoping to find clarity on this.

This is my data:

```
data = {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.MyListTitleListItem"},"Title ":"New Title"}
```

My code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://[SharePoint site]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyListTitle')/items?
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("POST");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue);

urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
osw.write(data);
urlConnection.connect();
```

Answer (score 2):

The extra space after "Title" will cause the 400 error.

```
"Title ":"New Title"
```

vs.

```
"Title":"New Title"
```

If you can get the full error message, you will probably see something like this:

```
"value": "The property 'Title ' does not exist on type 
'SP.Data.AnnouncementsListItem'. Make sure to only use 
property names that are defined by the type."
```

Comment: wow...sharp eyes :). Fixed the extra space in the title and implemented suggestion to get the full error message. Still seeing the issue and this is the error message: value: "A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected.

Comment: Maybe useful: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159601/a-node-of-type-endofinput-was-read-from-the-json-reader-when-trying-to-read-th

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JAVA, so just guessing... is the OutputStreamWriter (ows.write(data);) expecting an object, or a string of JSON text.

I.e.

```
data = {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.MyListTitleListItem"},"Title":"New Title"}
```

or

```
data = '{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.MyListTitleListItem"},"Title":"New Title"}'
```

Comment: Yup...finally solved this. It was indeed what form the data should be in the Output stream. I had been sending string - it was the issue. Sending it as bytes solved it.Thank you!